# xkb keyboard layout not showing up in trisquel and unity

Tags: x11, xfce, xkb, unity, trisquel

I followed [these](http://people.uleth.ca/~daniel.odonnell/Blog/custom-keyboard-in-linuxx11) instructions to form a keyboard layout which can be found [here](https://github.com/NiranjanTambe/Indic-IPA). Adding the keyboard-file to `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols` and adding the relevant information to `/usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/evdev.xml` worked in (at least) two systems with `ubuntu 16.04` as base and `xfce` desktop, but it isn't working in few other systems eg. `trisquel`, `ubuntu16.04 (unity desktop)`. I must be missing something. I have the following questions -

1. Where can I have the list of linux distributions which use `X11`?
2. How to make a customized keyboard accessible to all possible variants of linux which use `X11`?
3. Right now I have made my own repository on github. Can I fork my keyboard in the main repository? If yes what is the correct path to the repository? Searching `X11` in github results in numerous repositories out of which I don't know the correct one.